# Меняем картинку чекбоксами

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

> Есть главная картинка 1.png и 2 чекбокса. При нажатии на 1 чекбокс меняется главная картинка на 2.png, если выбираем оба чекбокса меняется на 3.png

```
<img src="img/1.png" width="310" height="280" id="glavnay" />
<input name="Краска" type="checkbox"  id="yslygi" />
<input name="Лак" type="checkbox"   id="lak" />



 var f=document.getElementById("glavnay").value;
    switch ($('input[type=checkbox]').click()) {
        case "yslygi" : replaceImg (f, "img/2.png");
        case "yslygi" || "lak" : replaceImg (f, "img/3.png");
    }
```

> Видимо что-то пишу не так,не работает...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так можно сделать:

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
  if($('#yslygi').prop('checked') && $('#lak').prop('checked')) { //если выбраны оба чекбокса...
      $('img').attr('src','http://vkusnosti.org/uploads/posts/2013-06/1371657136_jagodnij-pirog.jpg');
  } 
  else if($('#yslygi').prop('checked')) { //если выбран первый чекбокс...
$('img').attr('src','http://i1.smotra.ru/data/img/galleries/7184/7656/sm_img-41896_980x600.jpg');
  }
  else { //если ни один из чекбоксов не выбран
   $('img').attr('src','http://enolivier.com/img/frozen-fruit-smoothie/_fullsize/inspirational-frozen-smoothie-fruit-drink-shake-smoothie-shakes_frozen-fruit-smoothie.jpg');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://enolivier.com/img/frozen-fruit-smoothie/_fullsize/inspirational-frozen-smoothie-fruit-drink-shake-smoothie-shakes_frozen-fruit-smoothie.jpg" width="310" height="280" id="glavnay" />
<input name="Краска" type="checkbox"  id="yslygi" />
<input name="Лак" type="checkbox"  id="lak" />
```

Comment: Спасибо большущее!!!все работает)

Comment: а можно ли все-таки сделать через case?так как нужно чтобы менялась одна картинка при нажатии 3,4 чекбоксов

Comment: я сделала для 4 выбранных чекбоксов и не работает

Comment: @Лиана, лучше приведите свой код и я Вам объясню, почему не работает )) Через case я не представляю, как здесь сделать.

Comment: кстати в коде написано было $('img').attr... и менялись все картинки на странице при нажатии на чекбокс, я поменяла на $('#image').attr... задала <img id="image"... для 3 чекбоксов работало.Когда добавила 4 уже не меняет картинку.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rjntx8h0/2/ полный код

Comment: все заработало, id не верно указала.Можете на код глянуть,структура верная?

Comment: @Лиана, ну, если результат тот, которого Вы ожидали, значит всё ок )) Наверное, это всё можно как-то оптимизировать, но это уже если очень заморачиваться.

Comment: хорошо,спасибо!